# How to solve 403 forbidden error in wordpress?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, file-permissions

I have a `wordpress` website. It is showing this kind of errors for some files `Forbidden`

> You don't have permission to access
>   /wp-content/themes/clementina/assets/js/plugins.min.js on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

My website is misbehaving because of this error.

Comment: my site url is collectingcuriosities.com

Comment: Check permission of wp-content. The permission should be 755.

Comment: This is already set to 755

Answer (score 2):

Please set the permission to 0755 to your wp-content folder

Answer (score 1):

Will you please add this .htaccess file on root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: only that single js file is not included right ???
all other js css is working fine???

Comment: there are five file that are not executing.... have a look on this url http://collectingcuriosities.com/ and inspect element->console

Comment: and what is the permission of your htaccess file??

Comment: .htaccess file permission is set to 644

Comment: Then there is only last solution goto your appache configuration file and add this

<Directory "/var/www/add directory path here">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

How to solve 403 forbidden error in wordpress?

This will happened with the permission issue generally WordPress required few permission to execute

```
Wp-content - 775 
wp-admin - 775
wp-includes -  755   
.htaccess - 755
```

Then will fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

A 403 Forbidden error on WordPress can be caused by several factors. Here are some common solutions to resolve this issue:

**Permissions:** The error can occur if the permissions on the WordPress files or directories are incorrect. You can try changing the permissions on the files and directories to 755 or 744.

**.htaccess file:** The .htaccess file can also cause a 403 Forbidden error. You can try renaming the .htaccess file in the WordPress root directory to .htaccess_backup to see if this resolves the issue. If the issue is resolved, you can then regenerate a new .htaccess file.

**Plugins:** If the issue is caused by a plugin, you can try disabling all plugins to see if this resolves the issue. If the issue is resolved, you can then enable each plugin one by one until you find the plugin that is causing the issue.

**Theme:** The theme can also cause a 403 Forbidden error. You can try switching to a different theme to see if this resolves the issue.

**IP Blacklist:** If your IP address has been blacklisted, you may be receiving a 403 Forbidden error. You can try accessing the website from a different IP address or check the website's firewall to see if your IP address has been blocked.

**Mod Security:** If you have Mod Security installed, it may be causing the 403 Forbidden error. You can try disabling Mod Security to see if this resolves the issue.

**If the issue persists after trying these solutions, it is recommended to consult with a WordPress developer or hosting provider for further assistance.**